# syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ']'

Tags: php, html

I am getting the following error message. Can someone please help me.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ']' in /home/whilesto/public_html/includes/init.php on line 61

Following is the code from line 54 to 66

```
        if ($setts['is_mod_rewrite'])
{
    $valsArray = explode(",", $_REQUEST['rewrite_params']);
    $valsCnt = 0;
    $count_valsArray = count($valsArray);
    while ($valsCnt < $count_valsArray)
    {
        $_REQUEST[$valsArray[$valsCnt   1]] = $valsArray[$valsCnt];
        $_GET[$valsArray[$valsCnt   1]] = $valsArray[$valsCnt];
        $_POST[$valsArray[$valsCnt   1]] = $valsArray[$valsCnt];
        $valsCnt  = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, what is this? $valsArray[$valsCnt   1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies not only in line 61 but also in lines 62 and 63. You have to remove the `1` from between `$valsCount` and `]`:

```
        $_REQUEST[$valsArray[$valsCnt]] = $valsArray[$valsCnt];
        $_GET[$valsArray[$valsCnt]] = $valsArray[$valsCnt];
        $_POST[$valsArray[$valsCnt]] = $valsArray[$valsCnt];
```

It also seems to me that you’ve written an endless `while` loop. You may consider changing line 64 to:

```
        $valsCnt++;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks.But another error popped up.